# How can I get the grid done correctly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to put the grid in my graphic, and I'm getting this problem below. The grid style must be help lines, and dashed, this I know how to do, but the problem remains in put the grid correctly.

Here is the code that I'm using.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

    \begin{filecontents*}{dataCL.csv}
        x, y
        10, 0.7 
        15, 0.6
        20, 0.5
    \end{filecontents*}
    \begin{filecontents*}{dataCD.csv}
        x, y
        10, 0.4
        15, 0.3
        20, 0.2
    \end{filecontents*}

    \begin{document}


\pgfkeys{
   /pgf/number format/.cd, 
      set decimal separator={,{\!}},
      set thousands separator={}
}
\pgfplotsset{
   every axis/.append style = {
      line width = 0.5pt,
      tick style = {line width=1pt},
      grid style={dashed}
   }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % provide shared options here with pgfplotsset:
    \pgfplotsset{
        height=6cm, width=9cm,
        no markers=major
    }
    % this is the leftmost y axis (y2)
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,xmax=1,%--- CF
        xshift=0cm,%-- CF
        width=2cm,
        hide x axis, 
        axis y line*=left,
        ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
        ytick = {0,0.24,0.48,...,1.2},
        ylabel={$C_l$}
        ]
   \end{axis}
   \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=10,
        xshift=7cm,%-- CF
        width=2cm,
        hide x axis,
        axis y line*=right,
        ymin=0, ymax=0.5,
        ytick = {0,0.1,0.2,...,0.5},
        ylabel={$C_D$}
    ]
    \end{axis}
     \begin{axis}[
        height=2cm, 
        xmin=0, xmax=25,
        ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
        minor ytick = {0,5,10,...,25},
        axis x line*=bottom,
        hide y axis,
        xlabel={$\alpha$}
    ]
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
     xmin = 0, xmax=25,
     ymin = 0, ymax=1.2,
     hide x axis,
     hide y axis,
     ]
     \addplot+ [mark = none] table [col sep=comma, x=x, y=y]{dataCL.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
     xmin = 0, xmax=25,
     ymin = 0, ymax=0.5,
     hide x axis,
     hide y axis,
     ]
     \addplot+ [mark = none] table [col sep=comma, x=x, y=y]{dataCD.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[grid]

    \end{axis}


 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: I can't draw the scale correctly and the grid at same time]

Comment: Why are you using so many `axis` environments? Use only one.

Comment: Your grid looks fine, as @Qrrbrbirlbel says you should have the `addplots` in a single `axis`environment.

Comment: Because are three different axis, and each one have differents limits.

Comment: Actually the right curves are [link] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/6PYPG.jpg), there you can see what the grid is doing. I don't want that extra axis points, I just want that the grid between the y axis and x axis, without creat any extra points in the axis.

Comment: Pardon me, but I fail to see what you're trying to achieve with the graph you linked to. Why show two plots on the same graph if the x-ticks do not coincide? What is this graph supposed to tell your reader? Please consider presenting your data differently.

Comment: The two blue curves are Lift and Drag coeficients for a geometric perfil of a Wind Turbine blade vs attack angle of the blades. I'm trying to show what is happening with the two coeficients when the attack angle increase more then 10~15º. As you can see the drag coeficient, on the figure above with link, start growing and the other coeficient start decrease.

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to do that.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

    \begin{filecontents*}{dataCL.csv}
        x, y
        10, 0.7 
        15, 0.6
        20, 0.5
    \end{filecontents*}
    \begin{filecontents*}{dataCD.csv}
        x, y
        10, 0.4
        15, 0.3
        20, 0.2
    \end{filecontents*}

    \begin{document}


\pgfkeys{
   /pgf/number format/.cd, 
      set decimal separator={,{\!}},
      set thousands separator={}
}
\pgfplotsset{
   every axis/.append style = {
      line width = 0.5pt,
      tick style = {line width=1pt},
      grid style={dashed}
   }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % provide shared options here with pgfplotsset:
    \pgfplotsset{
        height=6cm, width=9cm,
        no markers=major
    }
    % this is the leftmost y axis (y2)
    \begin{axis}[ymajorgrids,
        xmin=0,xmax=1,%--- CF
       % xshift=0cm,%-- CF
        %width=2cm,
        hide x axis, 
        axis y line*=left,
        ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
        ytick = {0,0.24,0.48,...,1.2},
        ylabel={$C_l$}
        ]
   \end{axis}
   \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=10,
        xshift=7cm,%-- CF
        width=2cm,
        hide x axis,
        axis y line*=right,
        ymin=0, ymax=0.5,
        ytick = {0,0.1,0.2,...,0.5},
        ylabel={$C_D$}
    ]
    \end{axis}
     \begin{axis}[xmajorgrids,
        height=6cm, 
        xmin=0, xmax=25,
        ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
        minor ytick = {0,5,10,...,25},
        axis x line*=bottom,
        hide y axis,
        xlabel={$\alpha$}
    ]
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
     xmin = 0, xmax=25,
     ymin = 0, ymax=1.2,
     hide x axis,
     hide y axis,
     ]
     \addplot+ [mark = none] table [col sep=comma, x=x, y=y]{dataCL.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
     xmin = 0, xmax=25,
     ymin = 0, ymax=0.5,
     hide x axis,
     hide y axis,
     ]
     \addplot+ [mark = none] table [col sep=comma, x=x, y=y]{dataCD.csv};
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some explanation of what you did to resolve this issue.